# BigQuery: Aggregating distinct values in JSON

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table (few million rows) which I'm grouping by using some columns. One of other columns contains simple 1-layer key:value JSON with unknown keys. Let's say it's:
`{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2", "key3":"value33"}` in row1
and `{"key2": "value22", "key3": "value33"}` in row2.
Both row1 and row2 have the same columns used in groupby, so I want to aggregate these JSON results. Final result should be a JSON containing all keys which appeared in grouped rows, and their values should be lists of distinct values for these keys. For row1 and row2, result would be:
`{"key1": ["value1"], "key2": ["value2", "value22"], "key3":["value33"]}`
Is this possible to achieve such aggregation in normal query? Or I need to use e.g. remote function written in python?

I tried to find a proper solution, but I only saw similar logic for cases in which we have defined names of JSON keys. Here they can be random, and we're not aware what we will get.

Answer (score 0):

Use below (BigQuery Standard SQL)

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION  extract_keys(input STRING) RETURNS ARRAY<string> LANGUAGE js AS """
  return Object.keys(JSON.parse(input));
  """;
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION  extract_values(input STRING) RETURNS ARRAY<string> LANGUAGE js AS """
  return Object.values(JSON.parse(input));
  """;
SELECT id, FORMAT('{%s}', STRING_AGG(kv)) json
FROM (
  SELECT id, 
    FORMAT('"%s":%s', key, FORMAT('%T', ARRAY_AGG(val))) kv
  FROM your_table,
  UNNEST(extract_keys(json)) key WITH OFFSET
  JOIN UNNEST(extract_values(json)) val WITH OFFSET
  USING(OFFSET)      
  GROUP BY id, key
)
GROUP BY id
```

if applied to sample data as in your question

```
WITH your_table AS (
  SELECT 1 id, '{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2", "key3":"value33"}' json UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, '{"key2": "value22", "key3": "value33"}' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, '{"key2": "value22", "key3": "value33"}'
)
```

output is

[image]